# how to generate numbers for pagination?

Tags: python

I made a function that returns the number displayed for pagination. I want to get something like this (parentheses is the only show where the active site):

if pages < 10

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

if pages > 10

```
1 2 3 ... 20 [30] 40 ... 78 79 80
```

where [30] is active page. If active page < 3

```
1 2 [3] 4 ... 20 30 40 ... 78 79 80
```

etc. My code:

```
    count_all - number of all items
    items_on_page - items displayed on one page
    page - current page

    countpages = int(float(count_all+(items_on_page-1))/float(items_on_page))
    linkitems = 10

    if countpages > (linkitems-1):
        countpagesstr = list()
        for i in range(1,int(float(linkitems+(2))/float(3))):
            countpagesstr += [str(i)]

        countpagesstr += ['...']
        sr = int(countpages/2)
        for i in range(sr-1, sr+1):
            countpagesstr += [str(i)]

        countpagesstr += ['...']
        for i in range(countpages-3, countpages):
            countpagesstr += [str(i)]
    else:
        cp = list()
        for c in range(1,countpages+1):
            cp.append(str(c))
        countpagesstr = cp

    return countpagesstr
```

How to do it better?

Comment: Maybe a better place would be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What should it look like if the active page is 33?

Answer (score 0):

Well what you did there is the same as:

```
[str(i) for i in range((linkitems + 2) / 3)] + [' ... ', str(active_page - 1), '[' + str(active_page) + ']', str(active_page + 1), '...'] + [str(i) for i in range(cntitems-3, cntitems)]
```

Comment: Won't work: Given 20 items and active_page = 1, it would display `['0', '1', '2', '3', ' ... ', '0', '[1]', '2', '...', '17', '18', '19']`